# Sourcing Anaconda activate script vs. adding the Anaconda bin directory to PATH

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, anaconda

I would like to move to Anaconda Python as my default Python environment.

In order to use Anaconda over the system Python I have been looking at the following two options:

1. Adding the Anaconda bin path to my bash `PATH` variable (in my `.bashrc`) so that the Anaconda binaries take precedence over those elsewhere on the system.
2. Sourcing the Anaconda activate script in my bash shell (again, automated by adding it to my `.bashrc`).

As someone who is relatively new to Anaconda Python, I'm not sure which of the two approaches is generally considered as better. Therefor I was wondering if there is any general guidance in this regard?

As far as I can work out the main difference between the two approaches is that the activate script sets up a number of additional shell environment variables such as: `CONDA_PREFIX`, `PS1`, `CONDA_PS1_BACKUP` and `CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV`.

Comment: I guess if the machine job is only to serve with anaconda do it auto by `.bashrc` or add a script inside `/etc/init.d/anaconda` with `chmod +x`  when the machine start. But if is only for dev just add link to your menu and start it by hand when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having experimented with both approaches over the last couple of weeks I have settled on the first option: Adding the Anaconda binary path to the `PATH` variable in user `.bashrc` files.

I have found the benefits of this method to be:

1. Regardless of whether the Anaconda activate script is sourced in the user's `.bashrc`, when the user switches to one of their virtual environments and then runs `source deactivate` to deactivate the current environment they will always end up outside of the Anaconda environment. In this case, unless the Anaconda binary path has also been explicitly added to their `PATH` variable the `deactivate` script will remove the Ansible binary path from the `PATH` variable.
2. The Anaconda activate script performs a bunch of actions which may be an unnecessary overhead when performing non-Python related actions in ones shell, if it is sourced every time a new shell is started.
3. If one sets the Anaconda binaries to be in their `PATH` variable then it's simple enough to run `source activate` to enable the "root" Anaconda environment. (With either solution, something similar has to be done anyway if one is commonly making use of virtual environments.)